# How to execute code after 2 nested loops in node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm trying to find the lowest value ("best score") in 2 nested loops and then save the result after the loops are done. The following code seems to execute the final saving before the loops and not after them.

```
var bestScore = 300;
SaltEdge.getCustomerConnections(customerId, function(res1) {
    Promise.all(res1.json.data.map(function(connection) {
        return Promise.resolve()
            .then(function() {

                SaltEdge.getConnectionAccounts(connection.id, function(res2) {
                    if (res2.json.data) {
                        return Promise.all(res2.json.data.map(function(account) {

                            SaltEdge.get3MonthsIncome(connection.id, account.id, function(threeMonthsIncome) {
                                console.log('threeMonthsIncome', threeMonthsIncome);
                                var accountScore = SaltEdge.threeMonthsIncomeToScore(threeMonthsIncome);
                                console.log('account score', accountScore);
                                if (bestScore > accountScore) bestScore = accountScore;

                                console.log('best score', bestScore);
                                return bestScore;
                            });
                        }));
                    }
                });

            })
            .then(function(result) {
                return bestScore;
            });
    })
    ).then(function(res) {
        console.log("i'm here" + bestScore, res);
        if (bestScore < 300) {
            console.log('--update score', bestScore);
            Borrower.update(borrowerId, {salt_edge_score: bestScore}, function() {
                done(new Response(200,{ updated: true }));
            });
            resolve(bestScore);
        } else {
            done(new Response(200,{ updated: true }));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't insert plain callback asynchronous functions like `SaltEdge.getConnectionAccounts(connection.id, function(res2) {...});` in the middle of a promise chain.  When you do that, the promise chain will NOT wait for that or anything in its callback.  You NEED to promisify all asynchronous operations in the promise chain so you can chain them properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short version:

Aggregate all the `Promises` into one array and use `Promise.all()` with that array. Or have an array for the `Promise.all()` of the inner loops and use another `Promise.all()` to wait for them to all `resolve`. Data structure of result `[[...],[...],[...]]`.

#### Why it fails:

So your call:

```
SaltEdge.getConnectionAccounts(connection.id, function(res2) {
    if (res2.json.data) {
    // is never used
    return Promise.all(res2.json.data.map(function(account) {
```

runs into nothing because the `Promise.all()` is never consumed because the function is in a `.then()` block without a `return`, followed by a `.then()` that does nothing with a non existent value.

```
.then(function(result) {
    return bestScore;
});
```

However since you reassign `bestScore` in the callback of `getConnectionAccounts` and this is a global you will have a side effect. So when the code above runs `result` will be undefined and `bestScore` unknown at the time since you reassign it in a callback. This means that all the `Promises` from the `Promise.all()` should resolve to garbage. (some value)

#### How to for your case:

First order of business should be to get the reassignment, `if (bestScore > accountScore) bestScore = accountScore;`, some where to the end of the chain. Make it conditional that all Promises have to resolve where `Promise.all()` comes into play.

So contrary to the comment, you can insert asynchronous calls. BUT you have to return a `Promise` from within the `.then()`. Which means that either the callback has to resolve the returned `Promise` or the called function has to return a `Promise` of their own.

So does `SaltEdge.getConnectionAccounts()` return a `Promise`? If yes just `return` the function call. If not use something like this:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    SaltEdge.get3MonthsIncome(connection.id, account.id, function (threeMonthsIncome) {
        console.log('threeMonthsIncome', threeMonthsIncome);
        var accountScore = SaltEdge.threeMonthsIncomeToScore(threeMonthsIncome);
             console.log('account score', accountScore);
             if (bestScore > accountScore) bestScore = accountScore;

             console.log('best score', bestScore);
             resolve(bestScore);
     });
})
```

To recap: We now have one promise for each score. We can feed all these `Promises` to `Promise.all()` at once. Just return an array from within your inner `map()` and append a `flat()` to your outer `map()`.

```
Promise.all(
    res1.json.data.map(
        function (connection) {

            // will return an array of promises
            return SaltEdge.getConnectionAccounts(connection.id, function (res2) {
                if (res2.json.data) {
                    return res2.json.data.map(function (account) {
                        // for better readability return added
                        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                            SaltEdge.get3MonthsIncome(connection.id, account.id, function (threeMonthsIncome) {
                                console.log('threeMonthsIncome', threeMonthsIncome);
                                var accountScore = SaltEdge.threeMonthsIncomeToScore(threeMonthsIncome);
                                console.log('account score', accountScore);

                                // move this assignment
                                if (bestScore > accountScore) bestScore = accountScore;

                                console.log('best score', bestScore);
                                // resolving the promise inside the callback
                                resolve(bestScore);
                            });
                        })
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    // flat should get rid of the nested arrays
    ).flat()
) // use .then() for what to do with the array
```

The `Promise.all()` will resolve to an array of all values of all calls. That's when you execute your code after 2 loops.